# error: shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, flutter-ios-build

I am constantly getting an error while trying to archive my iOS app built in Flutter. I had uploaded a previous version of this app using a different PC.

[image]

I tried Flutter clean, deleting the `podfile.lock` file, I also used the command flutter build iOS.

I need to upload app to test flight. Any temporary fix would also help.

Comment: It looks like a permissions issue. For the named folder, have a look at the folder permissions at every level up to your user folder. One of them may have lost read or write permissions and that would need to be added again (using `chmod`) with the root account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission problem.

refer to this :- https://www.symscape.com/node/1727

along with /bin/sh I also gave permission to xcode.